# Jquery, $(this) outside function

Tags: jquery, function, this, each

I would like to trigger a function inside an `each loop`.
The problem comes from the `$(this)` which is **outside** the `each loop`

```
function look () {
    $(this).css("color","blue");
};

$(".text").each(function(){

    look();
    // other functions()
    //...
});
```

I know I can place my `$(this)`, inside the `each loop`, but I would like to proceed like this because I have many small functions to place. How can I do ? Thanks. Nicolas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
function look (el) {
    el.css("color","blue");
};

$(".text").each(function(){

    look($(this));

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use look.call(this) to change the context of this; From this way, you don't need change your function look().

Look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call